# Python 2.7 - manipulate some data from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

First of all I wanna emphasize that I'm a total beginner at python, the below code I made to manipulate some data from a CSV. I know that it's not the prettiest code and probably I could have made it more elegant, but it works, until a certain point and that's the reason I opened this question

```
import csv
from numpy import interp
from operator import sub
import math
import pandas as pd
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog as filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename= filedialog.askopenfilename( initialdir="C:/", title="select file", filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.CSV"), ("all files", "*.*")))



id_uri = []
ore = []
minute = []
zile = []
activi = []
listx = []
listsa = []
list_ore = []
listspi = []
listspf = []
list_min = []
zile_luna = 0
test = []
nume = []
with open (filename) as p, open ('activi.csv') as a:
        reader = csv.reader(p,delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
                id_uri.append(row[0])
                ore.append(row[1])
                minute.append(row[2])
                zile.append(row[3])
        reader = csv.reader(a)
        for row in reader:
                activi.append(row[0])
                nume.append(row[1])
id_uri = map(int, id_uri)
ore = map(float, ore)
minute = map(float, minute)
minute = interp(minute,[0,60],[0,100])
ore = ore + minute/100
zile = map(int, zile)
activi = map(int, activi)
zile_luna = len(set(zile))+1
mimin = 0
maxim = 0
def pontaj():
        global listx
        global listsa
        global listspi
        global listspf
        global list_ore
        global list_min
        global maxim
        global minim
        for x in range(3):
                for y in range(len(id_uri)):
                        if zile[y] == z:
                                if activi[x] == id_uri[y]:
                                        listx.append(ore[y])
                                        minim = min(listx)
                                        maxim = max(listx)
                listsa.append(maxim-minim)
                listx = []
        listspi = [int(i) for i in listsa]
        listspf = [i%1 for i in listsa]
        for i in range(len(listspf)):
                listspf[i] = round(listspf[i], 2)
                listspf[i] = listspf[i]*100
                listspf[i] = interp(listspf[i],[0,100],[0,60])
                listspf[i] = int(listspf[i])
        list_ore.append(listspi)
        list_min.append(listspf)
        listsa = []

for z in range(1,zile_luna):
        pontaj()
for sublst in list_ore:
        for item in range(len(sublst)):
                sublst[item] = str(sublst[item])
for sublst in list_min:
        for item in range(len(sublst)):
                sublst[item] = str(sublst[item])
for i in range(len(list_ore)):
        for j in range(len(list_ore[i])):    
                list_ore[i][j] = ' '.join(i + ':' + j for i,j in zip(list_ore[i][j],list_min[i][j]))
df = pd.DataFrame(list_ore)
df = df.T
nume = pd.Series(nume)
df['e'] = nume.values
df.to_csv('pontaj.csv', index = False, header = False)
print df
```

and the CSV file I read all the info from looks like this(employee code, hour, minute, day):

```
23,5,00,1
23,6,00,1
24,7,00,1
25,8,00,1
24,9,00,1
25,11,00,1
24,7,00,2
25,8,00,2
24,9,00,2
25,11,00,2
23,5,00,4
23,6,00,4
24,7,00,4
25,8,00,4
24,9,00,4
25,11,00,4
```

I have another CSV file that has employee code folowed by employee name like this:

```
23,aqwe
24,beww
25,cwww
```

Basically it's an attendance logger, it compares info from one CSV to another, finds the min and max hours in a certain day, subtracts min from max and writes this info in a list that is written to another csv.

Thing is, if all employees attend a certain day, all goes well, it calculates the attendance hours, puts them in the csv, all good. But what will happen if an employee skips one day? well as I found out, it ruins the calculation, because the code requires that all data must be consistent and in a perfect order.

The data written to the CSV file must finally look like this:

```
day1 day2 day3
hours hours hours employee_a
hours hours hours employee_b
hours hours hours employee_c
```

But if one skips a day, the hours get scrambled.

I've tried some different approaches but none worked, and I realize the problem is due to my simple way of thinking, but as I said, I only started with python a few days ago.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could improve the code to take the missed day of a certain employee in consideration and generate the data like so:

```
 day1 day2 day3
1:20 2:30 3:40 employee_a
1:20 2:30 3:40 employee_b
0:0  2:30 3:40 employee_c
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Honestly, your code is not maintainable - this is not an insult, but simply a fact (my first code looked worse...). I would suggest that you research how the library pandas works and use that for your task - it is the go to solution for reading and manipulating tabular data in python

Comment: Yes, I started with pandas, but due to lots of unknown stuff, I ended up choosing the simpler, but more complicated road.